# No "full global illumination" option in light path settings in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I saw the "full global illumination" option once, and I clicked the minus sign there. Now I only have this "Integrator Presets".

Did I accidentally delete "full global illumination"? How can I get it back?

There are surprisingly few Google hits on this.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you accidentally deleted the preset. Just hit the plus sign and set it to the below settings and label it full global illumination.

[image]

Comment: Can't believe this thing can be deleted from the software package... May I ask what are other presets? I remember I deleted more than this one. Would you mind post them here too? Thanks!

Comment: Oh I got it now. They are at `Blender/2.78/scripts/presets/cycles/integrator/full_global_illumination.py` and `/limited_global_illumination.py`.